# Recursively intercepting $http

Tags: angularjs, restful-architecture

In order to better consume a hateoas enabled rest api I got the idea to intercept http calls and add some methods to my resource objects before returning them.

The idea is that if the resource has an array of links I'll add methods to easy further http requests.

The below code is push to the interceptors array of a $httpProvider and does pretty much what I want.

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {

    var $http = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http');

    function flattenLinks(links) {
        for (var key in links) {
            var rel = links[key].rel;
            var href = links[key].href;
            links[rel] = href;
        }
    }

    return {
        'response': function responseHandler(response) {
            var data = response.data ? response.data : response;
            if(typeof data === 'string' || !data.hasOwnProperty('links')) {
                return response;
            }

            if(data.links instanceof Array) {
                flattenLinks(data.links);
            }

            if(data instanceof Array) {
                for(var key in data) {
                    responseHandler(data[key]);
                }
            }

            data.hasLink = function(link) {
                return link in data.links;
            };

            data.get = function(rel) {
                return $http.get(data.links[rel]);
            };

            data.delete = function(rel) {
                return $http.delete(data.links[rel]);
            };

            data.post = function(rel) {
                return $http.post(data.links[rel], data);
            };

            data.put = function(rel) {
                return $http.put(data.links[rel], data);
            };

            return response;
        }
    };
});
```

The problem is that when I use, as seen below, my added methods to do requests the response isn't handled by my interceptor. The $http.get, $http.delete, etc. done from within my interceptor isn't intercepted (naturally!).

```
    vm.someResourceObj.get('self').then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
```

So the question is. How do I get the internal calls to $http handled?

Comment: Not really clear what the problem is. Interceptor will run for all requests

Comment: As long as you make http request with $http, your interceptor should be call, can you add more details / explain what happens?

Comment: The interceptor isn't applied to the $http calls done from within the interceptor. The calls performed in the functions get, delete, post and put are not intercepted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - this is not an answer to you question =)

But it's a kind of advice: man, you are really try to develop a bicycle.

According to developers guide you should use `$resource` instead of `$http` to interact with **REST api**. Especially with **RESTful**.

`$resource` service will provide you functionality to make exactly what you want - to make requests like `User.get()` and after this `User.save()`, `User.update()`, etc.

My suggest is to create a `factory` for each entity(like "user", "account", etc), or for each workflow(like "sign up").

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app.factories.user', ['ngResource'])

    .factory('UserFactory', function ($resource) {

      var _userApi = {
        user: $resource('/user', {}, {})
      };

      return {
        getCurrentUser: function () {
          return _userApi.user.get(function (data) {
            // here we got data.user;
          }, function (response) {
            console.error(response.status);
          }).$promise;
        }
      };

    })
;
```

And use it in a controller:

```
.controller('UserPageCtrl', function ($scope, UserFactory) {

      var currentUser;

      $scope.getCurrentUser = function () {
        return UserFactory.getCurrentUser().success(function (user) {
          //here we got user
          currentUser = user;

          //now we able do stuf like
          //currentUser.save()
          //etc.
        }).error(function (err) {
          console.error(err);
        });
      };

    });
```

So, don't mind if examples above little bit... you know... let's say if you don't like it ))

Just take a look at `$resource` [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) (and [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource))

If you don't like resource, you can use third-party [restanguar](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) (or perhaps something else). But restangular is much more strict, so choose it only if you know for sure that your backend developers aren't idiots.

**UPD1:** About interceptors (I'll put here my working code for error intercepting, the idea of this code is to logout user when any request return `403 error` status):

You are able to add all facctory to global `$httpProvider`(at module config section).

Like this:

```
app.config(function  ($urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
      //Process backend errors
      $httpProvider.interceptors.push('errorsFactory');
})
```

And here is `errorsFactory`:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app.factories.errors', [])

    .factory('errorsFactory', function ($q) {

      var HTTP_STATUS = {
        FORBIDDEN: 403
      };

      return {
        response: function (response) { 
          if (response.status === HTTP_STATUS.FORBIDDEN) {
            //logout here
          }
          return response || $q.when(response);
        },
        responseError: function (rejection) { 
          if (rejection.status === HTTP_STATUS.FORBIDDEN) {
            //logout here
          }
          return $q.reject(rejection);
        }
      };
    })
;
```

Comment: But aren't $resource and restangular "path" based rather than hateoas based?

Comment: @user672009 Sure, but does it make sense? Anyway, I've update my answer already, perhaps it would help you

Comment: I understand your code, it makes sense :-) But that's pretty much what I'm trying to avoid. I don't want to have a factory for each of my business objects and I want my resources to be related by their hateoas links. So if the user has relatives I want to retrive them by doing user.get('relatives') and so on.

Comment: @user672009 Okay, please share you result here if you find out how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Use `$injector` to get `$http` instead of accessing it via `angular.`.

**Detailed Answer:**
The problem is how you inject `$http`. It seems that you get some `$http` that is outside of your app (I can't exactly say why, though). `var $http = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http');` doesn't do what you want (or what you think it does).

You could do `var $http = angular.element(document).injector().get('$http');` (or probably better use `$document` there), but imo you should use the `$injector`-service normally: you can just add `$injector` to your dependencies/inject statement and inside your interceptor use that to retrieve the service you want like: `var $http = $injector.get("$http");`

With that your interceptor will intercept the `$http`-calls it makes.