# Using $injector for $http and use $httprovider

Tags: angularjs

I need to inject in `$http` into service, because i aready use `$http` into `$httpProvider` for refresh token, then i got a recursive problem. Like this [Recursively intercepting $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221715/recursively-intercepting-http). The code above works, but i want to use https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar/ that use an `$httprovider` and dont work with my new injected `$http`.

There is a way to use the save `$httprovider` injecting with angular?

```
var OAuthService = ('OAuthService', function ($q, OAUTH) {

var $http = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http');


this.findGroup = function (id, openIdToken) {

    var defer = $q.defer();

    var params = {
        headers : {
            'Authorization' : openIdToken
        }
    };

    $http.get(OAUTH.baseURL + '/groups/' + id, params )
        .success(function (data) {
            defer.resolve(data);
        }).error(function (error) {
        defer.reject(error);
    });

    return defer.promise;

};
```

Comment: Your question is really unclear. Can you explain more precisely what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to use angular-loading-bar in this  $http injected.